# Alter todo with sharepoint workflow webservice

Tags: sharepoint, web-services, workflow

I have a workflow defined in Sharepoint which collects user data. The workflow generates a form with a simple user input text box and three buttons: Cancel, Complete Task, Save draft. How can i complete this task using the workflow webservice? I can change the text box's content, the percent complete, the status etc. via the workflowservice.AlterTodo method, but I can't accomplish completing the task.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Does anybody have some experience with completing todo's / tasks in a workflow trough the workflow webservice? 

The problem is, that my workflow is paused until someone completes this task.

Comment: I saw this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296356.aspx (with video) on the msdn, where the webservice was used to approve. The workflow goes on and is completed. I thougt it should be pretty the same to do this for collect feedback forms, but it looks like it isn't possible?

We want to work remote with Sharepoint items and workflow, so we have to use the webservices.

Any ideas to accomplish collecting data from users this way?